# Почему я не могу заполнить определенные области внутри path независимо от типа заливки?

Tags: html, svg

Я нарисовал зубчатое колесо, и я не могу заполнить область, которую хочу заполнить. Вы можете посмотреть здесь:

https://jsfiddle.net/9k451fb6/

Я хочу, чтобы часть была заполнена за пределами «отверстия» в центре, до зубцов, тогда как «отверстие» заполнялось вместе с частями краев зубцов (что само по себе любопытно для меня, так как путь один полный путь с одним закрытием (z) в конце, так почему же кажется, что каждая секция шестеренки закрыта?)

Я пробовал варианты заполнения, `fill-rule=nonzero` и evenodd, но ничего не изменилось.

Ниже код, который я использую. Обратите внимание, что он нарисован одним path. Однако я пробовал и этот метод, и закрытие контура (вставка z) непосредственно перед рисованием круга в середине («дыра»):

```html
<svg id="cogwheel_1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <path id="arc_path" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" fill="blue" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 120 5 A 30 30 0 0 0 179 5 L 211 15 M 211 15 A 30 30 0 0 0 259 50 L 278 77 M 278 77 A 30 30 0 0 0 296 133 L 296 166 M 296 166 A 30 30 0 0 0 278 222 L 259 249 M 259 249 A 30 30 0 0 0 211 284 L 179 294 M 179 294 A 30 30 0 0 0 120 294 L 88 284 M 88 284 A 30 30 0 0 0 40 249 L 21 222 M 21 222 A 30 30 0 0 0 3 166 L 3 133 M 3 133 A 30 30 0 0 0 21 77 L 40 50 M 40 50 A 30 30 0 0 0 88 15 L 120 5 M 150 200 A 50 50 0 1 0 149 200 z"></path>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why am I unable to fill certain areas within a path, regardless of fill-rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68653264/7394871) от участника  [@Allasso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2179138/allasso).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68653264/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, это то, чего вы хотите добиться:

```html
<svg id="cogwheel_1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <path id="arc_path" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" fill="blue" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 120 5 A 30 30 0 0 0 179 5 L 211 15 
A 30 30 0 0 0 259 50 L 278 77 
A 30 30 0 0 0 296 133 L 296 166 
A 30 30 0 0 0 278 222 L 259 249 
A 30 30 0 0 0 211 284 L 179 294 
A 30 30 0 0 0 120 294 L 88 284
A 30 30 0 0 0 40 249 L 21 222 
A 30 30 0 0 0 3 166 L 3 133
A 30 30 0 0 0 21 77 L 40 50
A 30 30 0 0 0 88 15 L 120 5 
M 150 200 A 50 50 0 1 0 149 200 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Я удалил команды `M` между зубцами шестеренки. Переходя к новой точке для каждого зуба, вы заставляли заполнять этот фрагмент.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68653413/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

В любом случае, на вопрос уже был дан ответ, я оставлю здесь свой подход.
Проблема с вашим svg заключалась в том, что каждый угол зубца зубчатого колеса начинал новый вспомогательный путь, узлы которого находились в том же положении следующих зубьев, но не были связаны друг с другом.
Я просто открыл файл в Inkscape, выделил все узлы и присоединился с помощью соответствующего инструмента.
**Примечание** на будущее: каждый раз, когда вы видите подобное поведение, в основном с svgs, экспортированным Illustrator, CorellDraw и некоторыми онлайн-редакторами, вы можете быть уверены, что где-то на пути есть перекрывающиеся узлы, но не связанные.

Обратите внимание на разницу между двумя углами. Тот, что расположен над двумя узлами, не подключен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, на самом деле вы получили серию подпутей, залитых синим цветом, как показано стрелкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это код в том виде, в каком [SVGO](https://github.com/juanfran/svgo-inkscape) очистил его после того, как Inkscape сохранил его.

```html
<svg id="cogwheel_1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<path id="arc_path" d="M 264.07142,186.6301 C 259.69918,200.23262 265.52681,215.03117 278,222 l -19,27 C 248.58911,238.28353 231.87939,236.86124 219.80706,245.66397 207.73474,254.46671 203.97989,270.81109 211,284 l -32,10 c -2.6299,-14.22385 -15.03507,-24.54564 -29.5,-24.54564 -14.46493,0 -26.8701,10.32179 -29.5,24.54564 L 88,284 C 95.020113,270.81109 91.265258,254.46671 79.192936,245.66397 67.120613,236.86124 50.410887,238.28353 40,249 L 21,222 C 33.47319,215.03117 39.300816,200.23262 34.928577,186.6301 30.556338,173.02758 17.197624,164.39607 3,166 l 0,-33 c 14.197624,1.60393 27.556338,-7.02758 31.928577,-20.6301 C 39.300816,98.767378 33.47319,83.968835 21,77 L 40,50 C 50.410887,60.716466 67.120613,62.138761 79.192936,53.336026 91.265258,44.533291 95.020113,28.188906 88,15 L 120,5 c 2.6299,14.223853 15.03507,24.545641 29.5,24.545641 14.46493,0 26.8701,-10.321788 29.5,-24.545641 l 32,10 c -7.02011,13.188906 -3.26526,29.533291 8.80706,38.336026 C 231.87939,62.138761 248.58911,60.716466 259,50 l 19,27 C 265.52681,83.968835 259.69918,98.767378 264.07142,112.3699 268.44366,125.97242 281.80238,134.60393 296,133 l 0,33 c -14.19762,-1.60393 -27.55634,7.02758 -31.92858,20.6301 z M 150,200 c 27.51544,-0.27517 49.63706,-22.73389 49.4979,-50.23579 -0.13917,-27.5005 -22.48529,-49.69493 -49.9979,-49.69493 -27.51261,0 -49.858733,22.19443 -49.997895,49.69493 C 99.362936,177.26611 121.48456,199.72483 149,200 Z"  style="fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:2"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68659930/7394871) от участника  [@SIMBIOSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15107450/simbiosis).</sub>